# CSS drop down menu won't center, despite usual tricks

Tags: css, menu, center

Having a devil of a time getting my CSS dropdown menu to center. I know this is question has been asked before, but their solutions don't seem to be working. I've tried the `margin:auto` trick, changed the `float:left` to `display:inline-block`, and tried to put it in an invisible, centered superlayer. Nothing helped. :) What am I missing?

```
.nav ul ul {
display:none;
}

.nav ul li:hover > ul {
display:block;
}

.nav ul {
display:inline-block;
position: absolute; 
padding: 0;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:0;
margin-bottom:0;

background:#fff8e0;
font-family: hofstad;
font-size:30px;
color:#6f0018;
padding-top:20;
padding-bottom:20;
list-style-type: none;
}


.nav ul li {
float:left;
margin-left:50;
margin-right:50;}

.nav ul li a {
;} !--main links, if they are links--!

.nav ul li:hover {
color:#980122;
}

.nav ul li:hover > ul { 
margin:0; 
padding-top:20;
padding-bottom:0;
padding-left:0;
padding-right:0;
} 

.nav ul li:hover > ul li {  
float:none; 
margin-left:0; 
margin-right:0;
padding-top:0;
padding-bottom:5;
padding-left:5;
padding-right:5;

}

.nav ul li:hover > ul li a {  
color:#980122; 
}

.nav ul li:hover > ul li a:hover { 
color:#6f0018;  
}
```

Comment: Mind setting up a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Post your HTML too...

Comment: add width to it. hope this works :)

`width:90%; margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 0):

Its a little hard without seeing it in action to debug.

But it looks initially like your UL is positioned as "absolute" as soon as you do that it is pulled out of the main document flow.

Try playing around with which parent element has a "relative" position for it to anchor to.